# The differences between a vector with $n$ dimensions with a vector with $n+1$ dimensions whose $n+1$ element is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-analysis

Regarding a geometrical point of view, is there any differences between a vector with n dimensions with a vector with n+1 dimensions whose first n elements are identical to elements of the first vector and its n+1 element is zero?

Comment: You need to provide more context to make sense of your question.

Comment: Technically they are incompatible objects, as they belong to spaces of a different dimension, but functionally they are identical. E.g. a 3D vector in $xyz$ space constrained to lie in the plane $xy$ vs. a vector in the plane $xy$.

Comment: Why the $(n+1)$th element? What if I only consider $n+1$ dimensional vectors whose first element is zero?

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: If $F$ is a field and $\pi_{n+1}\colon F^{n+1}\rightarrow F$ is the projection on the $n+1$-th coordinate, then $F^n$ and $\pi_{n+1}^{-1}(0)$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not in the vectors themselves, but in what one can *do* with the vectors.  You cannot add a vector in $n$ dimensions to one in $n+1$ dimensions, but of course you *can* add two vectors both in $n+1$ dimensions, even if the components of them happen to have value $0$.  Likewise, there are other operations that can only be implemented if two vectors "live" in the same-dimensional space, including cross product.